# How to find a list of some information by a list of ids in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am writing a project on **Express** and **MongoDB 5.0.18**.

I have a list of ids `[id1, id2, id3 ...]`, that I request from the client, and I want to respond with a list of objects like `[{title1, theme1}, {title2, theme2}, ....]`. (theme, topic and id are parts of some mongoose Model)

My question is what is the fastest and most productive way to do it?

I know about the `"$in"` operator, but I don't think it is the best choice for me. I'm right?

Comment: A simple $in operator will perfectly do the job.

Comment: The $in operator allows you to specify an array of values, and MongoDB will return documents that have a field matching any value in that array. In your case, you can use the $in operator to match the list of IDs and retrieve the corresponding objects efficiently.

Comment: Are there specific reasons that you believe `$in` is not a good choice for this situation? Were there specific alternatives that you were considering?